# Why WasteKing disposal throws water up?

Tags: plumbing, garbage-disposal

My old Waste King Special Edition 3/4 HP had this problem: when activated it started turning so rapidly that all water and filth accumulated in it gets thrown up into the air (splash guard did not help). It only happens in the first moment after activation - after that it worked OK.

Now it finally died and I am looking for a replacement. I do not want to get the same problem again.

Does anybody know what could have caused that problem? Was it common for that model?
I know that Waste King has high speed - 2700 RPMs, while Insinkerator only 1725. May be the high speed causes it? But then it should affect all Waste King models? Should I buy a different brand or different HP?
What is your experience?

Answer (score 1):

There's a good chance the disposal was larger than needed for your house hold. Three people households will do great with a 1/3 to 1/2 HP disposal. larger the 5 people would use the higher RPM and HP. Those high RPM models need to have a lot of stuff in them before turning them on. I've always had In-Sink-Erator disposals, 1/3 to 1/2 HP and have never had any problems, and that's with a household of 4.
Are you sure the splash guard hasn't been damaged or cut? I once got a call to replace one because the customer cut some of the fins out of it so stuff would go down faster. Then stuff splashed out so they wanted a new splash guard.
[image]

You might want to check the plumbing to make sure there's not a partial blockage that could be causing the initial back splash.

Comment: Does this mean that large families have to tolerate water and filth being thrown in their face? Also, High RPM is the main selling point of all Waste King models. 1/2 HP has 2600 RPM

Comment: No, but there would be more stuff in there when it was turned on and wouldn't have a tendency to splash around.... You had a special edition unit so there might not be a lot around to compare.  You  might want to check the plumbing to make sure there's not a partial blockage that could be causing the initial back splash.

Comment: I don't see how # of people in a household relates to disposal usage. I mean, the average 5-person household will run the disposal more often and for more "stuff" than a 2-person household. But each use of the disposal is a separate instance, and those individual uses vary depending on cooking style and other factors much more than the number of people. Though I do agree that 1/2 HP Insinkerator (I have 2, one for each sink, 1 replaced a few years ago - they last a long time) is just fine for most uses.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  I was basing on meal prep, turning it on after finishing peeling 6 potatoes as opposed to turning it on after finishing peeling 2 potatoes.... less splash  due to more stuff in there.

Comment: I have learned (to some degree the hard way), that when peeling potatoes (or carrots) that the best thing to do is peel into the sink then scoop up the vast majority of the peelings and put them in the trash. The few pieces that fell into the drain + the little bits that are hard to pick up get washed into the drain and the disposal takes care of them. Better for the disposal, your house plumbing and the waste treatment plant.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact   Maybe a bad example because we clean out the sink first too.  How about cleaning off 6 plates instead of two?

Comment: I've learned (again, took a few years to figure this out myself...) to scrape the vast majority of stuff into the trash, especially bones but most other stuff too unless it has a lot of liquid, and then rinse in the sink.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  Doesn't sound like you need a disposal.

Comment: I definitely do need it. It doesn't take much to clog things up, and letting everything go down straight would really lead to problems. But I've been told by plumbers (and learned the hard way) that disposals are not to be used for as much "stuff" as many people use them for. (There was the infamous chicken soup incident a few years ago - a lot of chicken soup and other stuff, despite having gone through the disposal, managed to clog the pipes. I was able to open up the pipe below the kitchen that was fed by both sinks...and I ended up covered in disposed chicken soup. Not fun.)

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Stay safe up there.

Comment: @JACK "Are you sure the splash guard hasn't been damaged or cut?" - may be, I do not know, I inherited it from previous owners. I noticed that segments of the splash guard kind of hang downward. I did not know whether it is normal or not. Anyway, I will, probably order 1/2 HP unit now.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that my problem is caused by incorrect plumbing, similar to 
[Help with Garbage Disposal install and high drain pipe](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/36050/help-with-garbage-disposal-install-and-high-drain-pipe)

Apparently previous owners (long time ago) installed a deeper sink, but forgot to lower the outlet pipe. There is no easy fix for that.

See also
[Drain and disposal outlet same height?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/126550/drain-and-disposal-outlet-same-height)
and 
[What is the minimum height for garbage disposal drain above the drain stub](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/81969/what-is-the-minimum-height-for-garbage-disposal-drain-above-the-drain-stub)

Answer (score 0):

You need a wye or diverted where the garbage disposal wasteline connects into the adjacent sinks wasteline.

https://www.acehardware.com/departments/plumbing/pipe-fittings/plastic-fittings/42623?x429=true&gclid=CjwKCAjwguzzBRBiEiwAgU0FT1x7zinDNbgiAB8UkJBAUYCBdMDt0umsWu7Ta73l136PILx4010ZuxoCgpUQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

If you look closely, you’ll see that the current waste line connects in as a “T”. You need to get the waste moving “down” the other wasteline rather than pushing the waste into the side of the other waste line when you turn the disposal on.

Comment: I have 2 sinks and had that problem (despite wye in the right place) with stuff coming out the second sink in the infamous chicken soup incident. But OP gave no indication of this being anything other than an ordinary single-sink setup.

Comment: Is there a picture you're looking at that we're not getting?